# Jenkins to Continue Build only if SCM Change Detected

Tags: git, jenkins, build

When manually triggering one of our Jenkins jobs to build (and then deploy) a Microserivce, it has a pre-build step to build our common code base (we have some common utility methods stored in a seperate java project). This means that before we build a microservice, we first build and deploy this common code project.

We're wondering how to ONLY build/deploy this common code project pre-step if there's been a change to that project.

Is there some way for Jenkins to check if there's been a change to a project, and only continue building the project if there has been a change?

Note: this is not the same as poll SCM, because the project isn't built upon a change being pushed to git - it's manually triggered and should only be run if a change is detected.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using Jenkins Github hooks using the Github plugin. This is more efficient as Jenkins doesn't need to poll the repo. Github will do the job for you and triggers a build when there is code commit...

Comment: This is a great suggestion, and it would surely work for most people. However, we're in a slightly complex scenerio, whereby we have all of our microservices under 1 git repo. Unfortunately, gitlab doesn't offer the functionality for webhooks with subdirectories... :(

Comment: This may be worth trying:  https://github.com/jenkinsci/gitlab-hook-plugin